# covariant and contravariant components and change of basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, tensor-products, multilinear-algebra

I encountered the following in reading about covariant and contravariant:

> In those discussions, you may see words to the effect that covariant 
>   components transform in the same way as basis vectors (“co” ≈ “with”),
>   and contravariant components transform in the opposite way to basis 
>   vectors (“contra” ≈ “against”). As you’ll see later in this chapter,
>   there’s plenty of truth in that description, but there’s also a major
>   pitfall. That’s because the “transformation” of basis vectors usually
>   refers to the conversion of the basis vectors in the original
>   (non-rotated) coordinate system to the different basis vectors which
>   point along the coordinate axes in the new (rotated) system, whereas
>   the “transformation” of vector components refers to the change in the
>   components of the same vector referred to two different sets of
>   coordinate axes.

Later on it shows the following:

$$\begin{pmatrix} \text{Components of}  \\
                  \text{same vector} \\
                  \text{in new system} \end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix} \text{Inverse}  \\
                  \text{transformation} \\
                  \text{matrix} \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} \text{Components of}  \\
                  \text{vector in} \\
                  \text{original system} \end{pmatrix}$$

$$\begin{pmatrix} \text{New basis}  \\
                  \text{vectors} \end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix} \text{Direct}  \\
                  \text{transformation} \\
                  \text{matrix} \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} \text{Original basis}  \\
                  \text{vectors}\end{pmatrix}$$

These confuse me because from change of basis we have $B'= BP$ and $[v]_{B'}=P[v]_B$.
The $[v]_{B'}=P[v]_B$ is the first of the aforementioned equations. But the second of them I don't understand since the book as shown above has the direct transformation matrix on the left side and not the right side. We could write $B'= BP = (BPB^{-1})B$ but if $BPB^{-1}$ is the direct transformation matrix then the $P$ in $[v]_{B'}=P[v]_B$ does not make sense as the inverse transformation matrix as the inverse of $BPB^{-1}$ is not $P$.

So then later on when I read the following:

> you can combine superscripted (contravariant) components with
>   subscripted (covariant) basis vectors

I don't know how to reconcile it with what I already know about change of basis.

Comment: here http://juanmarqz.wordpress.com/2012/02/16/change-of-basis-and-change-of-components/ there is a little example that wrote, it might help

Comment: I found this while learning about bases, dual bases and the components that go with each: If you have to *memorize* which is which, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: at https://www.math.ethz.ch/ (which is at Zurich) this notes are **state-of-the-art** for Bachelors, you'll find a very good exposition of the matters: https://www.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/fs2014/other/mla/ma.pdf

Comment: @user_of_math: then, what is the main *not-to-be-lost's* trick? :D

Comment: @user782220: hey! man don't let the +50  be lost!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand, WLOG let's take a basis change given by 
$$b_1={B^1}_1e_1+{B^2}_1e_2$$
$$b_2={B^1}_1e_1+{B^2}_2e_2$$
where $\{e_1,e_2\}$ is an old basis and $\{b_1,b_2\}$ is the new.
Relation which can be succintily
expressed as $b_i={B^s}_ie_s$ 
(here we see **how bases covariate** ).

Agree that the matrix of such data is
$$[B]=\begin{bmatrix}
{B^1}_1, {B^1}_2\\
{B^2}_1, {B^2}_2\\
\end{bmatrix}$$
Then, to get the new components of a vector 
$v=v^1e_1+v^2e_2$, 
you will see
that $$v_b=[B]^{-1}v_e,$$
(here we see **how components *contravariate*** ),
$v_e$ is a column arrange from the old components; $v_b$ is the data on the new components of the very same vector $v$.

Unfolded is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
w^1\\
w^2\\
\end{bmatrix}
\ =\
\begin{bmatrix}
{B^1}_1, {B^1}_2\\
{B^2}_1, {B^2}_2\\
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
v^1\\
v^2\\
\end{bmatrix}$$
such that $v=w^1b_1+w^2b_2$ in the new basis.

Take an explicit example to illuminate even more:
Let
$$b_1=e_1+2e_2,$$
$$b_2=e_1+3e_2,$$
be a basis change. Its change-of-basis matrix is
$[B]=
\begin{bmatrix}
1& 1\\
2&3\\
\end{bmatrix}
$.

Now solving for $e_i$ we get
$$e_1=3b_1-b_2,$$
$$e_2=-2b_1+b_2.$$
Which substitution on $v$ gives:
$$v=v^1(3b_1-b_2)+v^2(-2b_1+b_2).$$
This simplifies into
$$v=(3v^1-2v^2)b_1+(-v^1+v^2)b_2.$$

Now follow with your eyes the $[B]^{-1}v_e$ product:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
3&-1\\
-2&1\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
v^1\\
v^2\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
3v^1-v^2\\
-2v^1+v^2\\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: the steps are **solve-substitute-simplify**

Comment: **Cf.** http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1074985/change-of-basis-matrix-part-of-a-proof/1074995#1074995

Comment: @user782220: the issue of *covariant components* are better addressed once you consider **duality of vector spaces** or the use of **reciprocal basis**

Comment: Actually shouldn't the P you have written be actually it's transpose. The components of the old basis vectors are written in new basis vectors andd are place in a column. Then the covriant matrix is just inverse trasnpose of contravariant matrix. Or the basis transformation matrix writing in this way just a convention. Kindly let me know this.

Comment: What $P$ @Shashaank ?

Comment: P is the basis transformation matrix

Comment: I didn't use $P$ anywhere @Shashaank

Comment: yes and that is what I am saying if you take your trasnformation matrix as you have taken and not as how taken by user7530 in his answer below ( where you have commented too) the in your case it should be - covraint matrix is inverse transpose of contravariant matrix.... Let me know if you can see the crux of my argument. I guess I am not able to explain properly. It all depends how you arrange the components in the transformation eqn

Comment: @Shashaank, I see that a basis change by writting the new basis in terms the old basis that is **co-vary**, but the components from old to new use the **inverse** of the basis-change-matrix that is why the components **contra-vary**. I understand that other use a different convention but that ids frivolous

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to explain using a "foreign" vector space other than $\mathbb{R}^3$, such as the space of polynomials of degree $\leq 2$. Of course, all finite-dimensional real vector spaces of the same dimension are isomorphic, but hopefully this will eliminate some of the confusion that arises when everything in sight is $\mathbb{R}^3$.

So let's say I have a basis $B$ for these polynomials, say $\{1, x, x^2\}$. I can write any random element of my vector space, like $3x^2+2x+1$, as a linear combination of those basis elements: $1\cdot 1 + 2\cdot x + 3\cdot x^2$, so I might represent that polynomial as the vector $(1,2,3)$ in that basis.

Suppose I have a second basis $B'$ for these polynomials; let's say $\{x+1, x-1, x^2-1\}$. There are now *two* kinds of transformations relating $B$ to $B'$ I might be interested in.

1. How do I express the *new* basis vectors as linear combinations of the old? In other words, what is the matrix $P$ with
   $$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}x+1&x-1&x^2-1\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}1&x&x^2\end{array}\right]P?$$
   In this case it is
   $$P=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}1 & -1 & -1\\1 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1\end{array}\right].$$
   Notice that the components of $B$ and $B'$ are *different* polynomials. There is no relationship between the components of $B$ and $B'$ other than the fact that both bases span the whole space.
2. Given a vector in basis $B$, how do I write the *same* vector in basis $B'$? For instance, for the example of $3x^2 + 2x+1$ we saw that I could write it as $(1,2,3)$ in $B$. The *same* polynomial is $(3,-1,3)$ in the basis $B'$. And the two are related by
   $$\left[\begin{array}{c}3\\-1\\3\end{array}\right] = P^{-1}\left[\begin{array}{c}1\\2\\3\end{array}\right]$$
   This can be seen to work in general by first converting the component vector $v$ into the full polynomial $Bv$, the using the relationship $B' = BP$ to get that that polynomial can also be written as $B'P^{-1}v$ and so the coefficients of the polynomial in the basis $B'$ are $P^{-1}v$.

The two key points are that a) in transformation 1, the objects being transformed are *basis polynomials*, while in transformation 2, the objects are *vectors of real coefficients*, and b) that in transformation 2, the old coefficients and new coefficients represent the *same* polynomial, written in a new way. Compare to transformation 1, where the first basis polynomial of $B$ is *not* the same polynomial as the first basis polynomial of $B'$.

By the way: the language of covariant/contravariant vectors is too entrenched in physics to go anywhere unfortunately, but if you pick up a good book on Riemannian geometry and read at least the first few chapters up through the discussion of tangent space, cotangent space, and the musical isomorphisms, it may give you a new perspective on what is going on with all those upper/lower indices.

Comment: In the book it shows the direct transformation matrix on the left hand side whereas here you have it on the right side. That is what is confusing me.

Comment: The text you've reproduced has some textual descriptions but no equations or examples, so it's hard to tell exactly what the author intends; you can certainly transpose everything to get $P^T$ on the left if you'd like.

Comment: i wouldn't say "unfortunately" for the entrencheing of Physics and Maths :D

Comment: @janmarqz Certainly not! I was referring specifically to the "covariant" and "contravariant" formalism.

Comment: ok, *unfortunate* is the situation where someone isn't aware of the existence of "duality" at rank one tensors.

Comment: Actually shouldn't the P you have written be actually it's transpose. The components of the old basis vectors are written in new basis vectors andd are place in a column. Then the covriant matrix is just inverse trasnpose of contravariant matrix. Or the basis transformation matrix writing in this way just a convention. Kindly let me know this.

Answer (score 0):

I tracked down the book: *A Student's Guide to Vectors and Tensors* by Daniel Fleisch. In the section "Basis-vector transformations", which is the source of the equation
$$\begin{pmatrix} \text{New basis}  \\
                  \text{vectors} \end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix} \text{Direct}  \\
                  \text{transformation} \\
                  \text{matrix} \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} \text{Original basis}  \\
                  \text{vectors}\end{pmatrix}, \tag{1}$$
the author "derives" $(1)$ by considering the more concrete situation of rotating vectors in the plane. All of the example equations take the following form: If $v'$ is the result of rotating $v$ counterclockwise through an angle $\alpha$, then their $x$- and $y$-components are related by the matrix equation
$$ \begin{pmatrix} v'_x \\ v'_y\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix} \cos\alpha & -\sin\alpha \\ \sin\alpha & \cos\alpha \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} v_x \\ v_y\end{pmatrix}. $$
This generalizes to $$[v']_{B^\star} = Q(B^\star)[v]_{B^\star}, \tag{2}$$ where $B^\star$ is an arbitrary basis of the vector space. $Q(B^\star)$ is a matrix which appears to depend on the choice of $B^\star$: It can be shown that $Q(B) = P$ (one approach is to follow the commutative diagrams I produced for [the previous revision of this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1077317/3)), and then that $Q(B^\star)$ is related to $P$ by a similarity transformation. Even intuitively, we shouldn't expect $Q(B^\star)$ to be equal to $P$ in general: Equation $(2)$ expresses (the components of) each new basis vector as a function of (the components of) one corresponding original basis vector, while $B' = BP$ expresses each new basis vector as some linear combination of all original basis vectors.

Applying $(2)$ to the components of the basis vectors, we obtain
$$[B']_{B^\star} = Q(B^\star)[B]_{B^\star}, \tag{3}$$ which certainly looks similar to $(1)$. The major disrepancies that I perceive are

1. $Q(B^\star)$ is where you expected $P$ to be, and
2. The matrix $Q(B^\star)$ is acting on a matrix of components (an element of $\mathbb F^{n \times n}$), not on an ordered list of elements of the vector space itself (an element of $V^n$).

Discrepancy 1 is explained by the fact that the author seems to assume that $B^\star = B$; note that when he he "derives" $(1)$, he only considers the case in two dimensions where the basis vectors have components $(1,0)^\top$ and $(0,1)^\top$. As I noted before, $Q(B^\star)$ becomes $P$ when $B^\star = B$.

Discrepancy 2, on the other hand, can't really be reconciled. As can be seen from $B'=BP$, elements of $V^n$ are considered to be *row* hypervectors. Dimensional considerations thus forbid the left multiplication of elements of $V^n$ by matrices.

So I believe $(1)$ is badly phrased. In light of $(3)$, it should instead say something like
$$\begin{pmatrix} \text{Components} \\
                  \text{of new}  \\
                  \text{basis vectors} \end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}   \text{Matrix similar to}  \\
                  \text{direct transformation} \\
                  \text{matrix} \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}   \text{Components} \\
                  \text{of original}  \\
                  \text{basis vectors}\end{pmatrix}. \tag{$1'$}$$
If we assume that $B^\star = B$, then $(1')$ becomes
$$\begin{pmatrix} \text{Components} \\
                  \text{of new}  \\
                  \text{basis vectors} \end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}   \text{Direct}  \\
                  \text{transformation} \\
                  \text{matrix} \end{pmatrix} \cdot I =
\begin{pmatrix}   \text{Direct}  \\
                  \text{transformation} \\
                  \text{matrix} \end{pmatrix}.$$
Neither of these equations conflict with $B' = BP$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $V$ be generated by the collection of basic vectors 
$\{{\mathbf{b}}_1,{\mathbf{b}}_2,...,{\mathbf{b}}_n\}$. 
Without the use of dual-spaces people used to explain 
the effect in the components  $a^s$ of a vector
$${\mathbf{a}}=a^s{\mathbf{b}}_s,$$
in this way:

Let's $V\stackrel{B}\dashrightarrow V$ indicate a basis-change on $V$.

An important base-change in an $n$-dimensional-inner-product-vector-space $(V,\langle\ ,\rangle)$
is the ``take the reciprocal basis".
This is constructed as follows:

The Gram matrix for basis $\{\mathbf{b}_1,...,\mathbf{b}_n\}$ is $G=[g_{ij}]$, where
$g_{ij}=\langle\mathbf{b}_i,\mathbf{b}_j\rangle$ are the metric coefficients.

Since the $\{\mathbf{b}_i$ are linearly independent then $G$ is non-singular, and then $G^{-1}$ exists.
We symbolize as $G^{-1}=[g^{ij}]$. 
As one has got $1\!1=GG^{-1}$, this implies 
$g_{is}g^{sj}=\delta_i^j$.

Let's define a reciprocal base-vector as 
$$\mathbf{b}^k=g^{sk}\mathbf{b}_s. \qquad (1)$$

The collection $\{\mathbf{b}^1,...,\mathbf{b}^n\}$ will be a basis-change
$$V\stackrel{G^{-1}}\dashrightarrow V\qquad\mbox{
given by}\qquad \mathbf{b}_k\dashrightarrow \mathbf{b}^k,$$
because $G^{-1}$ is a non-singular matrix.

Then we are going to call covariant components of a vector $\mathbf{a}\in V$ the scalars $a_k$
intervening in 
$$\mathbf{a}=a_s\mathbf{b}^s.$$

By the use of $(1)$ above we will get
$$a_k=g_{ks}a^s.\qquad (2)$$

Here one can see that meanwhile $\mathbf{b}_k$ and $\mathbf{b}^k$ covariate with $G^{-1}$, then
$a_k$ needs $\left({G^{-1}}\right)^{-1} =G$ to variate from the old-components $a^k$ of vector $\mathbf{a}$,
i.e. contravariate.