# Finding the basis one forms (covectors) corresponding to a particular formulation of basis vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, tensors, general-relativity

This formulation of the basis may be wrong, or I may be missing something, but I can't see a way to formulate the covectors this particular basis:

\begin{align}
\vec{e}_0 &= \vec{x} + \vec{y} \tag{1} \\
\vec{e}_1 &= \vec{y} \tag{2}
\end{align}

where a general vector in the space can be determined by:

$$ \vec{v} = a\vec{x}+b\vec{y} $$

I understand that the simplest basis for this space would clearly be:

$$ \vec{e}_0 = \vec{x} \\ \vec{e}_1 = \vec{y} $$

for which the covectors would be:

$$ \tilde{\omega}^0 = \frac{\partial}{\partial \vec{x}} \\ \tilde{\omega}^0 = \frac{\partial}{\partial \vec{y}} $$

where the derivatives are to be interpreted as:

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \vec{x}} = \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1},\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}, \ldots \right) $$

In principle, the initial basis, (1) and (2) should have a corresponding basis in the dual space, since they span all the vectors and are linearly independent, but I cannot think of a function that would satisfy:

$$ \tilde{\omega}^\alpha(\vec{e}_\beta) = \delta^{\alpha}_{\beta}$$

(where $\delta$ is the Kronecker delta symbol)

Comment: When you write $\vec e_0 = x +y$, what do you mean by $x,y$? Are they vectors?  Then how can you take partial derivatives with respect to them?  Are they coordinates?  Then how can a vector be equal to a sum of coordinates?

Comment: They are meant to be vectors, sorry that isn't clear, also they should be derivatives with respect to all the coordinates of the vector in question, sorry that this also isn't clear.

Comment: check http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1068862/covariant-and-contravariant-components-and-change-of-basis/1082980#1082980 for a discussion ad hoc