# Intuition behind the relationship between basis-transformation and coordinate-transformation matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors, change-of-basis

I am having problems understanding the "intuition", based on vector projections, of the *basis transformation matrix*:

[image]
versus the *coordinate transformation matrix*:

[image]
as explained on [pages 9 and 10 of this *Introduction to Tensors* online booklet by Kees Dullemond & Kasper Peeter](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwl-HpVJ_5PecC1zQVNSUU1PTHc/view), leading on to the formula:

$$\vec v'= \left(\Lambda^{-1}\right)^\top \vec v$$

---

I see the intuition in equation $(2.2)$ looking at the beginning of [this youtube video](https://youtu.be/V5k_rDAoTvg), as applied to the change of coordinates of a differential directional vector from the $X$ coordinate system to the $Y$ coordinate system:

[image]

$\begin{align}
dY^1 &= \frac{\partial Y^1}{\partial X^1} dX^1 + \frac{\partial Y^1}{\partial X^2} dX^2 + \frac{\partial Y^1}{\partial X^3} dX^3 + \cdots + \frac{\partial Y^1}{\partial X^d} dX^d\\
dY^2 &= \frac{\partial Y^2}{\partial X^1} dX^1 + \frac{\partial Y^2}{\partial X^2} dX^2 + \frac{\partial Y^2}{\partial X^3} dX^3+\cdots+\frac{\partial Y^2}{\partial X^d} dX^d\\
\vdots\\
dY^d &= \frac{\partial Y^d}{\partial X^1} dX^1 + \frac{\partial Y^d}{\partial X^2} dX^2 + \frac{\partial Y^d}{\partial X^3} dX^3+\cdots+\frac{\partial Y^d}{\partial X^d} dX^d
\end{align}$

but I still don't see the role or difference with the **basis transformation basis** (equation 2.1), or the need for the transposition in the $\vec v'= \left(\Lambda^{-1}\right)^\top \vec v.$

Comment: The dual nature of basis transformations wrt to coordinate transformation has, indeed, to be considered as an important point in linear algebra. Are you aware of the presentation "alias-alibi" given in the famous book "Algebra" (MacLane and Birkhoff, 1967)? You should find this book in your library.

Comment: check http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1667915/change-of-basis/1667996#1667996 for an example of how to think in your case and within an use under a linear transformation

Comment: see also this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1005954/how-does-the-representation-of-co-vectors-change-if-we-change-the-basis-of-a-vec/1079587#1079587